# Compute unit normal vector of a plane in $R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

Consider the plane,  in $ℝ^3$ by the vector equation
$$x(s, t)=(1, -1, 2)+ s(1, 0, 1) + t(1, -1, 0);  s,t∈ℝ$$
Compute a unit normal vector, **n**, to this plane.

My attempt is the third normal vector is $\left(1,\frac{2s}{t}+1, 1 \right)$ and the unit normal vector I got is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt {3 +\frac{4s^2}{t^2}+\frac{4s}{t}}}\left(1, \frac{2s}{t}+1, 1\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

$$\textbf{n} = \frac{(1,0,1)\times(1,-1,0)}{\|(1,0,1)\times(1,-1,0)\|}$$

**EDIT**

Since $(1,0,1) = \textbf{i} + \textbf{k}$ and $(1,-1,0) = \textbf{i} - \textbf{j}$, one has that
\begin{align*}
(1,0,1)\times(1,-1,0) & = (\textbf{i}+\textbf{k})\times(\textbf{i}-\textbf{j}) = -\textbf{k} + \textbf{j} + \textbf{i} = (1,1,-1)
\end{align*}

Comment: with that I got **n** as (1, 1, -1) and the length would be sqrt3

Comment: I have edited my answer so you can compare with your result.

Comment: thank you! for the unit normal vector, should it be the form of length times n?

Comment: You've calculated it correctly, that is to say, $\|(1,1,-1)\| = \sqrt{3}$. So the answer is given by $(1,1,-1)/\sqrt{3}$.